# how to convert variable values addr, []net.IP to string?

Tags: go

```
addr,err := net.LookupIP(name)
fmt.Println(addr, err)

createdAt := time.Now()

resultdb,err := db.Exec("insert into users (TimeRequest,Domain, IP) values ($1, $2, $3 )",
createdAt, name, addr)
if err != nil{
   panic(err)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fmt.Sprintf("%s", ips)`: try it on [playground](https://play.golang.com/p/9Z9EWS1hB2u).

Alternatively you can use the `%q` verb to surround the individual values in double quotes: try it on [playground](https://play.golang.com/p/tbdZ50d2cv7).

If you don't like the surrounding brackets, remove them by slicing the string: [click](https://play.golang.com/p/994CFskVRoz).

If you want to control how the individual values are *separated* from each other you have to run a DIY loop and either, add the separator inside the loop [manually](https://play.golang.com/p/q6JypEKusJs), or produce a string slice and use [`strings.Join`](https://play.golang.com/p/uMMnfyae0jN) to insert the separator for you.

Comment: or simply call `addr.String()`?

Comment: @JimB `net.LookupIP` returns a slice of `net.IP` values, i.e. the type of `addr` is `[]net.IP` which is an unnamed type, hence it has no method, not even `String`.